# Left outer join performace issues in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

How to improve the performance of query given below

```
select 
     distinct o1.id as c1, 
              a1.id as c2,
              o1.t1_id as c3, 
              o1.t2_id as c4,
              o1.t_p_id as c5 
from 
     ord o1 
     left outer join 
     acc a1 
       on o1.end_user_id=a1.id 
     left outer join 
     acc a2 
       on 1.t1_id=a2.id 
     left outer join 
     acc a3 
       on o1.t2_id=a3.id 
     left outer join 
     acc a4 on 
       o1.t_p_id=account4_.id 
where 
     a1.account_id=1 or a2.account_id=1 or a3.account_id=1 or a4.account_id=1;
```

Comment: Please read this: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions and post more info.

Comment: Impossible to say anything without table DDL, indexes, `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output, server configuration...

Comment: Details please. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Look I'm very willing to help out.  But you've given us next to nothing to go on.

Answer (score 1):

it looks to me that so many **left outer join** on the same acc table might be the reason cause the performance issue.

I would suggest to figure out your intent and then try to eliminate so many left joins on the same table.

for general analysises, I think @ScottMarlowe is right, you need to give more infomation, like the index, the explain result, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but from my point of view instead of using 'left join' you could use 'exists' command.

I've tried to write your query with 'exists' command like below:

```
select 
     distinct o1.id as c1, 
              a1.id as c2,
              o1.t1_id as c3, 
              o1.t2_id as c4,
              o1.t_p_id as c5 
from ord o1 
        where exists (select 1 
                        from acc a1 where o1.end_user_id=a1.id and a1.account_id=1)
        or exists (select 1 
                        from acc a2 where o1.end_user_id=a2.id and a2.account_id=1)  
        or exists (select 1 
                        from acc a3 where o1.end_user_id=a3.id and a3.account_id=1)  
        or exists (select 1 
                        from acc a4 where o1.end_user_id=a4.id and a4.account_id=1);
```

I hope it helps.